# I want to create more triggers on the same table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables that I want to be synchronized when insert, update or delete
can I create more than one trigger on the same table??

I already wrote code like that .. but it doesn't work .. but when I create only one trigger it works correctly.

the code is something like that:

CREATE TRIGGER photosinsert BEFORE INSERT ON photos
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO old_photo SET PhotoID = NEW.photo_id, photo_original = NEW.file_name
    ;
  END;

delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER photosupdate BEFORE UPDATE ON photos
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE old_photo SET photo_original = NEW.file_name
    WHERE
    PhotoID = NEW.photo_id
    ;
  END;

delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER photosdelete BEFORE DELETE ON photos
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM old_photo WHERE
    PhotoID = OLD.photo_id
    ;
  END;

---

is there a solution for that, please?

Answer (score 0):

Put all code into single trigger.
You can use multiple statements between BEGIN and END

Comment: Thanks Nakti, I tried to do that but it fails.

But I found the solution .. all I did is removing delimiters and BEGIN , END

the code will be like that:

CREATE TRIGGER photosinsert BEFORE INSERT ON photos FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO old_photo SET PhotoID = NEW.photo_id, photo_original = NEW.file_name ;


CREATE TRIGGER photosupdate BEFORE UPDATE ON photos FOR EACH ROW UPDATE old_photo SET photo_original = NEW.file_name WHERE PhotoID = NEW.photo_id ;

CREATE TRIGGER photosdelete BEFORE DELETE ON photos FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM old_photo WHERE PhotoID = OLD.photo_id ;